# .Net Framework 4.8 why oh why

Tags: .net, powershell, windows-server-2016

I'm trying to install the .Net Framework 4.8 using Packer to customize an AWS 2016 Server Base image with a powershell script that is run during the packing process.  However it seems to be a 50/50 chance that the framework will install.  I'm using the following statements in the powershell script and will install without any issues when I do it on the machine as a manual step.

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088631 -OutFile C:\temp\dotnet.4.8.exe # Download from MS
Write-Host "Installing 4.8"
Start-Process C:\temp\dotnet.4.8.exe -ArgumentList "/q /norestart /log c:\temp\" -Wait #Fire a new process to install silently
Write-Host "Installed 4.8 $LASTEXITCODE"
```

What I'm suspecting is that it isn't even starting as the log file never gets generated and I can verify that it does write the file as when I manually run the commands the file shows up after a few seconds and it continuously written to over the few min period that the installation takes.

I'm seeing no errors in the packer output and no errors being reported in the Event Viewer.
Packers' output is simply the Installing and Installed write statements.

I have referenced this [document from MS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers#command-line-options) as the installer doesn't seem to have an help mode to display what options are available.

Should I be calling the executable differently to guarantee it starts as an unattended install?

Comment: So, what errors *do* you get when you **disable** the [`/q` quiet mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/deployment/deployment-guide-for-developers#command-line-options)?

Comment: How do you invoke the the script automatically? Using a scheduled task? If yes, what are the triggers? Did you take in account for: [Windows fast logon optimalization](https://support.microsoft.com/nl-nl/help/305293/description-of-the-windows-fast-logon-optimization-feature)?

Comment: There could be a GPO rule that disables running executables from the Temp directory or even AV software preventing it. Also, the executable is downloaded, so have you tried [Unblock-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/unblock-file) or downloading to a different folder?

Comment: @iRon if I removed that it would hang as the gui would wait for input and since it’s running the commands with winrm there is nothing to connect to and click

Comment: @Theo the machine is a golden image from AWS. The customization steps are done with packer from Hasicorp and the instance is not connected to a domain. The file is unblocked as I can launch an instance from the image and run the powershell commands above without any issues.

Answer (score 1):

what about something like this?

```
$myURL="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2088631"
$myOutFile="C:\temp\dotnet.4.8.exe"
        
    if ( !(test-path -path $myOutFile)  ) {
        New-Item -Path 'c:\temp' -ItemType Directory
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest $myURL -UseBasicParsing
        [IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($myOutFile, $response.Content)
    }


    if ( (test-path -path $myOutFile)  ) {
       Write-Host "Installing 4.8"
    Start-Process C:\temp\dotnet.4.8.exe -ArgumentList "/q /norestart /log c:\temp\" -Wait #Fire a new process to install silently
    Write-Host "Installed 4.8 $LASTEXITCODE"
}
```

Comment: For windows 10 I had to do this:
`code`    DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NetFx3
`code`    DISM.exe /online /enable-feature /all /featurename:NetFx4

Answer (score 1):

The .Net 4.8 installer does have a help prompt if you run

```
Start-Process "PathTo.NetInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "/?"
```

This will display a long help list that explains that you need to run the installer with the syntax of:

```
Setup /switches go here
```

So for your example you would run:

```
Start-Process "PathTo.NetInstaller.exe" -ArgumentList "Setup /q /norestart /log c:\temp\" -Wait
```

Answer (score -3):

To install Microsoft .NET Framework 4.8, run the following command from the command line or from PowerShell: choco install dotnetfx

Comment: This required to be chocolaty pre-installed.

Comment: Downvoted because the answer assumes chocolatey is installed - and the OP is not asking how to using chocolatey package manager.